# Run OWASP ZAP (zaproxy) on ubuntu

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, zap, snap

Since firefox was moved to snap, I had problems to run Owasp ZAP on my ubuntu.

Even worse, because chrome (chromium) doesn't seem to work well either.

How can it be run successfully using chrome and/or firefox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to get it working both for chrome and firefox.

Steps:

1. install zap via snap: `sudo snap install zaproxy --classic`
2. run zap: `zaproxy`
3. once it starts and you have updated the plugins, restart it.
4. go to `Tools` -> `Options` and select `Display`.
5. Mark the option `Enable app integration in containers`.
6. Now select `Selenium` in the left menu.
7. change webdriver locations. Use `/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver` for chrome and `/snap/bin/firefox.geckodriver` for firefox. [image]
8. save changes.

Comment: MagMax - thanks for this! I'll see if we can either improve the ZAP docs or (even better) auto configuring ZAP to handle this situation - https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/issues/8078

Comment: @SimonBennetts it would be really great to set those options by default in the snap package!